# Multiple Model on same ActiveForm yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

have multiple model on same form
I dont want to save data on both model but i just want to display one variable on view file

I have 2 tables 
`Organiser` and `Event`
`Organiser` will log in and `Create Event` 
Now there are few fields which are common in both tables
so when logged in user click on `Create Event` button i want to display `address` from `Organiser` table on the form

This is what i have done until now
which may not be the right approach
so let me know if that can be achieved any other simpler way

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Event();

    $model2 = $this->findModel2(Yii::$app->user->id);


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if($_POST['User']['address'] == null)
        {
            $model->location = $model2->address;
        }
        else{
            $model->location = $_POST['User']['address'];
        }

        $model->is_active = 1 ;

        $model->save();


        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'model2' => $model2
        ]);
    }
}
protected function findModel2($id)
{
    if (($model2 = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model2;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not     exist.');
    }
}
```

And here is my `_form.php` code

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'create-event-form'
    ]
]); ?>


 <?= $form->field($model, 'interest_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Areaintrest::find()->all(),'id','area_intrest'),
    ['prompt'=> 'Select Event Category']
) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
   <?php
      if ($model->isNewRecord){
        echo $form->field($model2,'address')->textInput(['class' => 'placepicker form-control'])->label('Location');
    }
    else
        echo $form->field($model,'location')->textInput(['class' => 'placepicker form-control']);

?>

<di"form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update',     ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Now the problem here seems is that when it comes to saving part throws `error` saying `unknown property address` because that field doesnt exists in the database table `Event`
i just want that data to display it on the location field of my `create form`

so what should i do here

Here is the table structure

```
Organiser          Event 
organiser_id       event_id
username           organiser_id 
clubname           title
image              location
email
firstname
lastname    
address
```

Error page says something like this

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Getting unknown property: common\models\Event::address
```

And here is my `Event` model

```
class Event extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
      return 'event';
    }


public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['organiser_id', 'interest_id', 'title', 'location'], 'required'],
        [['organiser_id', 'interest_id'], 'integer'],
        [['title', 'location'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'organiser_id' => 'Organiser ID',
        'interest_id' => 'Event Type',
        'title' => 'Event Title',
        'location' => 'Location'

    ];
}


public function getOrganiser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['organiser_id' => 'organiser_id']);
}
```

}

Here is my `User` model represent `Organiser` table and model name in frontend model `SignUp.php`

```
   class SignupForm extends Model
{
public $username;
public $address;
public $password;
public $password_repeat;



public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['username', 'required'], 
        ['address', 'required'],
        ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],


        [['file'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],



        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],

        ['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'password_repeat' => 'Confirm Password',
        'address' => 'Address',
        'username' => 'Username',
    ];
}



public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $model = new SignupForm();
        $user->address = $this->address;
        $user->username = $this->username;

        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        if ($user->save()) {
            return $user;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

So i want to display the `organiser.address` on the `Create event` form in the field `location`
Hope you can understand it now
thank you

Comment: i am not getting it exactly. Can you show your table structure?

Comment: @InsaneSkull i have updated the database structure. All i want to do is display values on a field from another table as default value.

Comment: You can add **Virtual Attributes** with name `address` in your model check this  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/

Comment: you can create object of `organiser` table and pass with create.  For ex. `$model3 = new Organiser();` and `return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'model2' => $model2, 'model3' => $model3
        ]);`

Comment: @ganeshGhalame thats exactly what i did.. i have  added a attribute `address` in rule section of `event` model

Comment: @InsaneSkull i did that. You can see that in my `ActionCreate` code i attached in the question. My `Organiser` model is `User` in the project

Comment: Why do you think it should be here?
    if($_POST['User']['address'] == null)
    {
            $model->location = $model2->address;
    }
It should be $_POST['Event']['address'], check firebug or something like that.

Comment: error screenshot please.

Comment: @AntonM. Because if the record is new than the name of my form field is `address`. and if its update form than field name is `location`.So if its create form and the value is null than i want to get the value from `Organiser.address` table and store it in database of `event.location`

Comment: @InsaneSkulll Included the error lines in question

Comment: @MikeRoss so in that case you can use `$model->isNewRecord`

Comment: please remove `address` attribute from `event` model it's not needed there and try. your address will came from `user` model.

Comment: @InsaneSkull that seems to fix the problem. But how can i make the validation work. Can i import the same validation which was on the `Organiser` model or i have to implement manually for this `view` form.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll i feel like i am passing unnecessary variables to the view form. I ony need 1 field `organiser.address` and display it on `Event` form but i am passing whole `model` with all unnecessary attribute. Let me know if there is any other way to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: Sorry names for model make me miss something. Show User model structure please.

Comment: And i can`t understand why you need field address from user, why not location from Event, and before render call if it is new model $model->location = $model2->address;
And also you search for user twice.

Comment: @AntonM. I know my code is mess. I want to get the data which is in `organiser.address` and display in the `event` create form field `event.location` so that user dont have fill up the same form again. Thats the main thing i want to do. And `organiser` is the table name but the model name in my project for `organiser` is `User` Hope you got the idea. Thank you

Comment: it will import validation rules from `user` model. so u pass both models.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll yeah thats what i thought should happen but its not happening. Because in my `User` model the `address` field is required but when i import it on `Event` create form its not required field anymore. Its just normal input field. Thats why i have to check the `[$_POST]` variable before saving.

Comment: your `$model2` has all the fields of `organiser` and validation of that. in this case show `User` model also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be your function should look like

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $event= new Event();

    $user= $this->findModel2(Yii::$app->user->id);
    $event->location = $user->address;

    if ($event->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $event->save()) {//active can set by default validator
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $event->id]);
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'event' => $event
    ]);

}
```

And in form you show location always. Then you can use it in update and create as well without ifs in view. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Perfect solution... This way i dont have to pass multiple models to the form and no unnecessary if conditions.. Thank you very much